# Why does flexWrap: 'wrap' doesn't work in my React Native application?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

```html
<View style={{
  flex: 1,
  height: 1200,
  width: 200,
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center'
}}>
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
  }}>
    <Image source={require('./assets/zodiac/Aries.svg.png')} style={{width: undefined, height: '100%', resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
  </View>

  {/* 11 more similarly sized images in View containers */}

</View>
```

When the `height` property of the parent `View` is 1200, the following is the result:

[image: views are stacked one below the other]

But when the `height` is changed to 600, instead of wrapping around as it should because of the `flexWrap: 'wrap'` property, the child Views get squeezed to accommodate the new `height`.

[image: when the views are squeezed to accommodate new height]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with how you have defined the style in the child view components

```
style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
  }}
```

Replace this with

```
style={{
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
  }}
```

This should do the job for you. What happens when you define a flex for each of the child view components is it fits them within the parent view according to the relative flex values set, irrespective of what you set as the heights and width.

Answer (score 0):

When the height of the content is greater than the height of the Screen, always think to use `ScrollVIew` instead
You for a better UI it's also better to use `Dimension` package like

```
import {Dimension} from 'react-native';
//////////
const HEIGHT_DEVICE = Dimension.get('window').height;
///////////
```

Then use this prop as you like

Comment: I want the height of the content to be within the height of the screen. All I want is the 12 inner `Views` to be in two columns instead of one.

Comment: You can also use a FlatList with numCol props equals to 2

Comment: This will have the same design no matter the height of the screen